# F-statistic for classification, two ways to calculate the numerator; are they the same?

Tags: self-study, scikit-learn, f-statistic

[This question on F-scores for classification problems](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/74465/77875) (specifically for classification; `f_classif`) has two answers. Each answer shows a different way to calculate F-score, in particular differences in **the numerator** of the F-score. **Both answers produce the same number/same value**;

My question is: **are the two answers *mathematically* equivalent?**

To simplify things, the question asks about only **two groups** (blue group (which has $n$ instances) and red group (which has $m$ instances))

- [Technique A answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/74486/77875) (consistent with other sites/answers, like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/301959/90687))
- [Technique B answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/94090/77875), which references the [StatsQuest video](https://youtu.be/NF5_btOaCig)

**Technique A formula:**
Notice this technique compares **group means** to the **total mean**...

(Note the degrees of freedom part (dividing by $(p_{fit} - p_{mean})$) is implied; there are two groups, therefore $p_{fit} - p_{mean} = 2-1 = 1$; so it's division by 1.)

$$
n(\bar{x}_{blue}-\bar{x})^2 + m(\bar{x}_{red} - \bar{x})^2
$$

**Technique B formula:**
Notice this technique compares $x_i$ values to the **total mean**, and $x_i$ values to the **group means**...

$$
(
  \sum_{i=1}^{n_{all}} (x_i - \bar{x})^2 
  - (
  \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x}_{blue})^2
  +\sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_i - \bar{x}_{red})^2
  )
)
$$

And [this notebook shows my attempt](https://gist.github.com/theredpea/a18a1c1ce2ecae389546e1f24755b45b#Numerators-are-equivalent) to conclude the techniques are equivalent;

- indeed both techniques produce the same number/same value (given the same data).
- I try to show both formulas are mathematically equivalent (not my expertise!) - see the bottom of the notebook with the header **Numerators are equivalent**  (or [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4ipz.png) for a screenshot of my math...)

---

Other questions I've read, but I can't tell if they answer my question here...

- [Most similar](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538828/reconciling-f-statistic-derived-in-two-different-ways) asks about two versions of calculating F-statistic
- [Referenced by above](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258461/proof-that-f-statistic-follows-f-distribution), which seems to give the formula in Technique B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are equivalent in this context.  In brief, the first formula is the sums of squares for the between-group calculation; the second formula is the total sums of squares less the within-group sums of squares.  Because
$$SS_\text{between} + SS_\text{within}= SS_\text{total}$$
these formulas will give the same result.